# uitextview should reflect the changes as the uislider is moved horizontally

Tags: iphone, ipad

i took a viewbased application and i placed a uislider and a uitextview on the controller's view.my requirement is as i move the slider horizontally the changes should continuously reflect in the textview.and if i enter  a value in the textview within the range of slider,the slider should move to the respective position taking value from the textview.

tnx in advance
dinakar

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you set up the relevant objects in Interface Builder and your interface and implementation files? Please post your code so far. (We're not here to write it for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a selector to the slider as follows,

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In the function **sliderChanged** code as follows,

```
textView.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", slider.value];
```

Similarly, in UITextView delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
slider.value=[textView.text floatValue];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way of implementing ur idea. Are you doing like this?